# const_cast: override a const status

Tags: c++, constants, undefined-behavior, const-cast

I am experimenting with const_cast operator and trying to override a const status of the parameter o passed as an argument:

```
void function1 (const Object *o)
{
    ...
    function2( const_cast < Object *> ( o ) ); //Exception in g++
}

void function2 (Object *o) {}
```

But overriding a const status of o throws an exception in g++ (GNU/Linux), in VS 2010 (Win) it works well ...

Is there any more reliable way how to override a const status of a function parameter?

**Update:**

MSDN write: You cannot use the const_cast operator to directly override a constant variable's constant status :-(.

Comment: What exception are you getting? The code you posted is fine in g++.

Comment: Please show us where you call `function1()`, and keep in mind that using `const_cast` to remove constness from a truly-const object (a `const Object` in this case) results in undefined behavior, up to and including exceptions.

Comment: Can you make the code you show a *complete* (but still minimal) example? It's hard to understand what you're seeing from this fragment.

Comment: @cdhowie: only if someone uses the resulting pointer-to-non-const to attempt to modify the object. `const int i = 0; int *p = const_cast<int*>(&i); std::cout << *p;` is OK.

Comment: @cdhowie. I am afraid, that this exception represents an undefined behavior :-(. This code is only illustration, the real code with exceptions is a part of an extensive library...

Comment: `const_cast` isn't magic, and almost all of its naive CV-removing uses are in fact undefined behaviour. It's only intended for something like `strchr` where you reuse one piece of code for two different constnesses.

Comment: @SteveJessop Of course, but I really doubt that this example reflects the OP's actual code.  The odds here are that the object pointed to really is const.

Comment: @cdhowie: I'm not talking about whether the object is const (although if it were non-const, that also would prevent there being any UB). I'm talking about whether the pointer-to-non-const is used to modify the object, or only to read it. The latter would happen for example if the reason you const-cast is in order to work around an incorrect third-party interface, which does not modify the object but isn't marked const.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> MSDN write: You cannot use the const_cast operator to directly override a constant variable's constant status :-(.

`const_cast` allows you to strip `const` specifier from the pointer, but it does not affect the "const status" of the value itself. Compiler might decide to put the value into read-only memory (well, it's const!) and then an attempt to modify it, even through `const_cast`, might result in access violation.

Here is a code snippet:

```
static const int A = 1; // it's constant, it might appear on a read-only memory page
static int B = 2; // it's a regular variable

const int* pA = &A; // a const pointer
int* pB1 = &B; // a pointer
const int* pB2 = &B; // a const pointer to regular variable

*pA = 0; // Compiler error, we are not allowed to modify const
*const_cast<int*>(pA) = 1; // Runtime error, although const specifier is stripped from the variable, it is still on read-only memory and is not available for updates
*pB1 = 2; // OK
*pB2 = 3; // Compiler error, we are not allowed to modify const
*const_cast<int*>(pB2) = 4; // OK, we stripped const specifier and unlocked update, and the value is availalbe for update too because it is a regular variable
```

That is, `const_cast` removes const specifier during compile time, however it is not its purpose, authority or design to alter access mode of the underlying memory.